# Search with PHP in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am coding a search with PHP from MySql database. I am putting items into different tables by type into the database. And I would like to code a search in my webpage so that it would show all the items from the table when a user writes the type of the items. But I am stuck with this idea as I know only how to search in the tables themselves, but not for a table with SQL. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Are you searching for table name or contents ?

Comment: For both - table and contents inside it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'DB Name';
```

Comment: I tried this code, but the error occurs : "unknown column table_name in field list". Do you have any insights about this?